# Finding all rows with class attribute string match using Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this snippet of code:

```
page.css('tr').each do |row|
  # determine if this row is a player row
  is_player = row.attributes["class"].value.include?("player") rescue false
```

and I'm wondering if there is a way to use Nokogiri to search the class attribute of each row for the "player" string.

I tried doing something like `page.search("//tr[@class~='player']")` but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Is the class not accessed with `.attr('class')`?

Comment: @RichieAHB, I'm not sure what you mean, like this?: `row.attr("class").value.include?("player")`

Comment: Why don't you save us some time and supply a minimal example of HTML that demonstrates what you're working on. By doing so you help us help you, and that speeds up getting a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
page.xpath "//*[contains(@class, 'player')]"
```

Please note, that both `playerx` and `xplayer` are matched as well, so you probably would check for the exact class later on, or use more exact match:

```
page.xpath "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' player ')]"
```